# cshtml with Javascript li

Tags: javascript, razor

I build this li with a tags in code and wanted to add edit function so I created the click event. I then set the index to the name. I was then thinking I would get the index in the click event. I am getting "Edit" '0' when I look at it in Chrome. Is there a better way to do this?

Code

```
  <a href='#' name='Edit''" + index + "' class='glyphicon-pencil edit-reference' title='Edit'></a>

    $(".references-list").on("click", ".edit-reference", function () {
                console.log("edit-reference");
                console.log(index);
                return false;
            });
```

Chrome

```
<a href="#" name="Edit" '0'="" class="glyphicon-pencil edit-reference" title="Edit"></a>
```

Comment: Try: `name='Edit" + index + "'`

Comment: thanks that worked how would I get the index value in the click event?

Comment: What is this supposed to be?  `'0'=""`?

Comment: Should be the index value.

Comment: add a data attribute like `data-index='" + index + "'` and inside click access it like `var index = $(this).data('index')`

Comment: You should use data attributes and follow the HTML spec.  An attribute named "0" isn't right.